# Static UITableViewCell backgroundView

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

In my project I have tableViews with static cells as well as tableViews with dynamic cells. In order to customized I've managed to get a gradient background on the cells (grouped sytle).

It works ok with dynamic TableViews as I set the background view in cellForRowAtIndex... according to the position of the row (Top, Bottom, Middle or single).

However, when I try to implement it on the static tableview cells, it doesn't work. I've tried to implement the cellForRowAtindex... but it crashes.

Does someone have an idea?

Update: the code for cellForRow..

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];    

    UACellBackgroundView *bgw=[[UACellBackgroundView alloc]init];

    if (indexPath.row==0) {

        bgw.position = UACellBackgroundViewPositionTop;
        cell.backgroundView=bgw;

    }else if (indexPath.row==2){

        bgw.position = UACellBackgroundViewPositionBottom;
        cell.backgroundView=bgw;

    }else {
        bgw.position = UACellBackgroundViewPositionMiddle;
        cell.backgroundView=bgw;
    }

  //  cell.backgroundView=bgw;


    return cell;
}
```

By the way, the Background view I got it from here: http://code.coneybeare.net/how-to-make-custom-drawn-gradient-backgrounds  and here: http://pessoal.org/blog/2009/02/25/customizing-the-background-border-colors-of-a-uitableview/

if somebody is interested

Comment: Crashes with what?  And kind of log or breakpoints?

Comment: reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'
I think the compiler wants me to implement the datasource and so on.

Comment: Wrong code then. Look for the method -objectAtIndex.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like you are alloc the UITablViewCell, you need to alloc the cell.

For example:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        // alloc the UITableViewCell
        // remeber if you are not using ARC you need to autorelease this cell
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = @"Cell Name";
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"Cell Detail";

    return cell;
}
```

Add this statement:

```
if (cell == nil) {
    // alloc the UITableViewCell
    // remeber if you are not using ARC you need to autorelease this cell
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This actually works, but it destroys the static content of the cell.  What I have done is to create an outlet for each static cell and add the background view on viewDidLoad. It works as long as the style of the cell is set as Custom.

Comment: @Marcal i'm not understanding why you would not just add the background to the cell for the cellForRowAtIndexPath, the whole purpose of that method is to setup the cells for the table.  Just add a different background depending on which cell it is.  The first will have a top background, the last will have a bottom background, and every other cells will have middle background.

Comment: Well, I've done it and it works. But as I said, if I set this up on cellForRow, the static content I've dragged into the cell in Storyboard just disappears because the code overrules the storyboard, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a UITableViewController subclass with a static table you should not try to dequeue cells.
Instead you should ask `super` for the cell. The superclass will get the cell from the storyboard and you can configure it.

Something like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [super tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    UIView *selectedBackgroundView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    cell.selectedBackgroundView = selectedBackgroundView;
    cell.selectedBackgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor mb_tableViewSelectionColor];
    return cell;
}
```

Works for all other attributes as well.